# Expresión regular Ayuda

Tags: regex

Tengo problemas para optimizar una regex

El log viene de un Cisco WSA

https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/wsa/wsa11-0/user_guide/b_WSA_UserGuide/b_WSA_UserGuide_chapter_010111.html

Ej de log:

```
<14>Oct 04 10:08:59 access_log: Info: 1538640538.827 6 10.180.14.23 TCP_DENIED/403 0 GET http://www.url.com/ "usuario" NONE/- - BLOCK_WBRS-descargas-redes-DefaultGroup-NONE-NONE-NONE <IW_infr,-6.0,-,"-",-,-,-,-,"-",-,-,-,"-",-,-,"-","-",-,-,IW_infr,-,"-","othermalware","Unknown","Unknown","-","-",0.00,0,-,"-","-",-,"-",-,-,"-","-",-,-,"-">
```

y quiero de una forma optimizada sacar cada uno de los 41 campos que hay entre los <> (Access Log Scanning Verdict Entries) que van separados por ,

porque mi Siem dice que mi formula degrada y que la optimice (se que no es lo ideal) pero no consigo dar con otro regex

```
\s\<([^\,]+),(.*?),(.*?),"(.*?)",(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),"(.*?)",(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),"(.*?)",(.*?),(.*?),"(.*?)","(.*?)",(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),"(.*?)","(.*?)","(.*?)","(.*?)","(.*?)","(.*?)",(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),"(.*?)","(.*?)",(.*?),"(.*?)",(.*?),(.*?),"(.*?)","(.*?)",(.*?),(.*?),"(.*?)">
```

Ahí capturaba el campo_x con el grupo n que yo dijera

Gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: Hola, por favor, javi. Mira de darle formato tando a la expresión regular como al contenido de log. Mira de añadir algunas líneas más de log. Además, comentar parece imposible que esa expresión regular funcione porque está buscando comas `,` pero la línea de log no tiene ni una. No sé si ha sido error a la hora de poner aquí la línea de log. Por favor, especifica una entrada, y marca claramente lo que la expresión regular debería encontrar, y especifica si debe usar grupos de captura.

Comment: Y en qué lenguaje porque no todos soportan las mismas expresiones regulares

Answer (score 3):

No necesitas un Regex para eso.
Si todos los campos estan separados por ',' basta con hacer un split
Esto es , **de lejos**, mucho mas eficiente que `Regex` en este caso.

C#

```
var arregloDePosiciones =  todaLaCadena.Split(',');

foreach(var campo in arregloDePosiciones ){
    Console.WriteLine(campo);
}
```

JS

```
var arregloDePosiciones =  todaLaCadena.split(",");

arregloDePosiciones.forEach(
     function(item, index){
          console.log(item);
});
```

El primer campo del arreglo en ambos casos contiene toda la cadena anterior a `IW_infr`por lo que puedes omitirlo si lo deseas.

Comment: Hola @JuanK, un par de cosas para que la respuesta quede 'redonda': creo que el primer fragmento solo debería capturar `IW_infr`, pero tal como está captura todo la línea hasta `IW_infr`. A los otros campos deberían quitarse las comillas que rodean el dato. Y el console.log recibe campo pero debería ser item. Y la función `forEach` debería tener la `E` mayúscula.

Comment: lo he cambiado ayer, gracias

Comment: Bien! Pero faltaría un poco para hacer exactamente lo que hacía el código de OP. Faltaría quitar las comillas de los campos que los tengan y que el primer dato empiece en `IW_infr` en lugar de el principio de la línea

Answer (score 0):

Si puedes utilizar algún tipo de función `split`, sería lo más adecuado.

Sin embargo, si has de seguir con una expresión regular por algún otro motivo (típicamente en lugar de tener tu propio script, dependes de alguna utilidad que te pida una expresión regular como entrada), entonces podrías probar la siguiente expresión regular:

`^.[^<]*<([^,]+),([^,]*),([^,]*),"([^"]*)",([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),"([^"]*)",([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),"([^"]*)",([^,]*),([^,]*),"([^"]*)","([^"]*)",([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),"([^"]*)","([^"]*)","([^"]*)","([^"]*)","([^"]*)","([^"]*)",([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),"([^"]*)","([^"]*)",([^,]*),"([^"]*)",([^,]*),([^,]*),"([^"]*)","([^"]*)",([^,]*),([^,]*),"([^"]*)">`

Tiene un 'coste' de 203 pasos, comparados con la tuya original que tiene un coste de 548 pasos.

**[Expresión regular optimizada](https://regex101.com/r/M5QtSN/2/)**

[Expresión regular original](https://regex101.com/r/6DSJ4M/1/)